# Images are not uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to upload an image in codigniter but unable to do so when I try it shows me an error array to string conversion

```
<?php 
public function do_upload() {
$config['upload_path'] = base_url().'assets/uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '100';
$config['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['max_height']  = '768';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->do_upload();
if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', $error);
        redirect('admin/theme');
} else {
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Which line is this error?

Comment: can you tell us on which line the error shows up?

Comment: Error on line 25 <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success_msg'); ?>

Comment: can you please `var_dump($this->session->flashdata('success_msg'));` and show us the outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`base_url()` is return `HTTP` path not directory path, you should use directory path for upload content.

change

`$config['upload_path'] = base_url().'assets/uploads/';`

to

`$config['upload_path'] = getcwd().'assets/uploads/';`

you can use [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) native PHP function to get project root directory, and CI is also provides constant variable `FCPATH` for root directory.

Comment: Not working either :( Let me show my form field 
<?php echo form_upload('pic'); ?> is this okay ?

Comment: form field fine, but you should change `base_url` http path to directory path.

Comment: `$this->upload->display_errors();` the method returns string so you can assign data into variable instead of array variable `$error = $this->upload->display_errors();`

Comment: I changed the field  getcwd().'assets/uploads/' and the assets folders is located on main directory cms_project ->assets not inside application

Comment: great, it should work... for debug you can see cwd path `echo getchw();` then place proper path.

Comment: You did not select a file to upload.
C:\wamp\www\cms_project/assets/uploads/

Comment: if(isset($error)) {
        foreach($error as $err) {
         echo $err;
        }
        echo  getcwd().'/assets/uploads/';
        }

Comment: ok use file name in `do_upload()` method `$this->upload->do_upload('pic')` another if `$error` variable is array then you can use loop otherwise if string then use `echo $error`

Answer (score 1):

You are uploding  your files two time. After first uploding every thing is vanished and you have nothing to upload

```
$this->upload->do_upload();// first time
if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {// second time
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', $error);
        redirect('admin/theme');
}
```

Just comment it

```
// $this->upload->do_upload();// comment this line
```

**EDIT**

You can send your message into set_flashdata() as

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file_name')) {// add file name here
    $error = $this->upload->display_errors();// remove array from here

    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', $error);
        redirect('admin/theme');
}
```

To read a flashdata variable:

```
$this->session->flashdata('success_msg');
```

Comment: Commented the line but still getting same errror
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: admin/theme.php

Line Number: 25

Comment: admin/theme.php
Line 24 <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
Line 25 <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success_msg'); ?>
Line 26 <?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/do_upload'); ?>

Comment: You did not select a file to upload. Strange as I selected the file

Comment: which version of CI you use??

Comment: `$this->upload->do_upload('file_name')) {// add file name here`

Answer (score 1):

Array to string conversion usually shows up, when you try to echo an Array.

so it seems, that the problem lies on this line:

```
echo validation_errors();
```

To avoid this error but still print out the values in the array use `Foreach()`.

This Code should solve your problem:

```
foreach (validation_errors() as $error) { 
    //I assume you get an array as a return value
    echo $error;
}
```

**EDIT**

This answer doesn't help anymore, as the author edited his question

Comment: This would still help him out :)

Comment: Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: as said, i assume you get an array as a return value. if not, it doesn't work :-)

Comment: You did not select a file to upload.

I placed for each now and it shows me this error 
<?php echo form_upload('pic'); ?> am I doing something wrong